# Android Binding get the name of the service that sent a message

Tags: android, bind

I have 2 service (Service A and B) that exchange data using binding. One of the 2 services (Service A) can bind to multiple services (now there is only Service B, but I'll have to add also other 2 services, C and D). All the services exchanges data in the same way and use the same messages.

I would like to know if it is possible to retrieve the name of the service that sent the message.

In particular my Service A when receives a message from B needs to store this information so when it receives the same message from C or D behaves differently. Is it possible without adding a String in a bundle attached to the Message?

This is the code where I would like to get this info in Service A

```
class myHandler extends Handler {
       @Override
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            String senderName;

            switch (msg.what) {
                case REGISTER:
                    senderName = ???

                    addToRecord(senderName);

                    sendConfirm(msg.replyTo, SUCCESS);

                    break;
                case UNREGISTER:
                    senderName = ???

                    removeFromRecord(senderName);

                    sendConfirm(msg.replyTo, SUCCESS);

                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Message's structure like :

```
Message{
  what,arg1,arg2,obj,when,data,replyTo.
}
```

and Bind of Messenger :

```
oneway interface IMessenger {
  void send(in Message msg);
}
```

So your background service can not obtain the name of original service.

As you said, putting a String in a bundle to the message can resolve this.

In some circumstances for avoid fake name, you can assign the particular String to the original service when binding. And let them resend to your service when call the remote method.